# Tri-object converter for selected list in JSF

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets

We've got `h:selectOneMenu` that receive the value from a thirdparty 
`thirdpartyObj.type` (got a get and set) 
`thirdpartyObj.type.codeName` (got only a get and the set is called `toCodeName` instead)
The list of option is given by the thirdpartyService `codeNameBean.codeNameList` (the type of the object)

```
    <h:selectOneMenu id="currentType" value="#{client.thirdpartyObj.Type}">
        <f:converter converterId="codeNameConverter" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{codeNameBean.codeNameList}" />
        <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="previous" ajaxSingle="true" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

I'm trying to make a converter with these value, since it not working I created a get `thirdpartyObj.getCodeName` and `setcodeName` and created a converter for codename with string.

Is there any other way to do this, can it all be done in the converter instead?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what problem you have with it since you didn't tell anything about the occurred errors. At least, the converter will be applied on the `value` of the `h:selectOneMenu` **and** on each item represented by the `value` of the `f:selectItems`. So they both needs to be of the same type. It's namely a common mistake to think that it applies on the `value` of the `h:selectOneMenu` only.